# preprocessing class error, "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'str'"

Tags: python, python-class, data-preprocessing

So I did an nlp project earlier now I have pickled the model and trying to apply it to a new data set, the data set is something I scrapped from twitter. So of course the new dataframe doesn't have the same columns as the old dataset, so I am making a class to preprocess the data to make closer the old dataframe which was used for the nlp project. This is what I did

```
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def fit(self, text_column):
    df = pd.DataFrame(text_column)
    df.text_length = self.text_length(text_column)
    df.num_capital_letters = self.num_capital_letters(text_column)
    df.percentage_of_capital_letters = self.percentage_of_capital_letters(text_column)
    df.greater_than_50_percent = self.greater_than_50_percent(text_column)
    df.reading_level = self.reading_level(text_column)
    #df =pd.DataFrame(Text.df_user_tweets
    return df

  def text_length(self,column):
    return column.apply(lambda x: len(x))
  def num_capital_letters(self,column):
    return column.apply.str.findall(r"[A-Z]").str.len()
  def percentage_of_capital_letters(self,column):
    return column.apply.str.findall(r"[A-Z]").str.len()/column.apply(lambda x: len(x))
  def greater_than_50_percent(self,column): 
    return column.apply(lambda x:  x>= .5 )
  def reading_level(self,column):
    return column.apply(lambda x :textstat.flesch_reading_ease(x))

pre = Preprocesser()

pre.fit(text_column = df_user_tweets.Text)
```

This is the error that I got

```
<ipython-input-136-3b74ba5d2425> in num_capital_letters(self, column)
     17     return column.apply(lambda x: len(x))
     18   def num_capital_letters(self,column):
---> 19     return column.apply.str.findall(r"[A-Z]").len()
     20   def percentage_of_capital_letters(self,column):
     21     return column.apply.str.findall(r"[A-Z]").str.len()/column.apply(lambda x: len(x))

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'str'
```

It sounds like my error is in line 19 but not sure what I need to do fix it, appreciate any help

Comment: I mean it says it right there... you're trying to access a `str` attribute on a function and functions don't have such an attribute. What do you want to achieve with that?

Answer (score 1):

`df_user_tweets.Text` is of type `pd.Series` and it has a method `apply`. this method takes a `lambda` function to do some work on values of that `Series` (which is a column), and it does not have an `str` attribute.

So instead of `column.apply.findall` do `column.str.findall`.

- you can find the doc of pandas here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html?highlight=str#pandas.Series.str